# How to use classes from a neighbouring subproject during configuration phase

Tags: gradle

I want to compile one subproject, then have those classes on the classpath **while building** the other subproject. (A custom tass would use classes created by the first one).

Currently I'm trying:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath project(':MyOtherProject')
    }
}
```

... with the following result:

> Cannot use project dependencies in a script classpath definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot build something to be used to build the something. (something being the multi-project build here)

You either need to make the `MyOtherProject` a complete separate build, that you either install to some repository and then depend on it per coordinates or trigger that separate build during configuration phase or your build, then depending on its outcomes.

The other alternative is, that you put it into `buildSrc` project. This is a full multi-project build contained in your root project that is built and added to the classpath of the main build scripts automatically by Gradle and is meant for Plugins and Custom tasks that you do not want to use in other builds also and thus do not make them a separate build.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite the disappointment after the many heroic songs they sing about Gradle...

Comment: What exactly do you find disappointing? Gradle is the best build tool out there and you can do virtually anything with it. But how should it solve a hen and egg problem? Well, actually it did solve it by the facility that is called `buildSrc` project as I just told you. And if for some reason you need to do it anyway in that subproject, you can even do that, though it is very poor build design. Just make the subproject build as independent as necessary to build alone and then build it during configuration phase as standalone project.

Comment: What I read about buildSrc is that it is rather than exception than the rule, for example a buildSrc subproject can not depend on additional buildSrc style dependencies (not chainable). - For context: my build chain looks like: antlr (generate grammar) -> custom task (parse language file to XML) -> xslt (generate java classes from xml) -> main program

Comment: A `buildSrc` build is a full separate multi-project build in which you can do anything you can do in any other Gradle multi-project build. The only difference is, that it is built and the results added to the runtime classpath of your main build script automatically. Maybe it is seen as exceptional case, as you would normally make it a separate stand-alone project to use the result in multiple builds. But if it is only used in this one build, I don't see any reason not to use it as long as it is not officially deprecated.